# z3 install in Redhat platform

Tags: installation, z3

Can the latest z3 be installed in the Redhat linux platform? There is no mention to this platform in the https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, we currently do not provide pre-compiled binaries for RedHat Linux. We currently only provide pre-compiled binaries for: Ubuntu and Debian. We also regularly compile Z3 on Fedora. 
That being said, you should be able to compile Z3 on RedHat Linux without problems. In particular, we have managed to compile the `unstable` (work-in-progress) branch in many different platforms. 
See this related question:

- [Installation of Z3 on a posix system without python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642209/installation-of-z3-on-a-posix-system-without-python)

[This link](http://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation) has instructions on how to compile Z3 on Linux.